# Is it possible to display 2 different css in one site?

Tags: html, css

I want to redesign a old Website. Just a hobby project. It has a very outdated Bootstrap 2 Frontend and lots of Elements in the body. I just wanted to give it a new Navbar and Top Bar, ect.

But when i update the css files to newer one the website content looks awful, otherwise if i let the old one the new navbar looks awful, so is it possible to have two seperated css?

I already tested iframe srcdoc and its not rly working...

Thanks!

Comment: You can have two different `<link href="/media/examples/link-element-example.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Do you mean that?

Comment: You have to learn css specificity, or at least complete a basic html-css tutorial before starting to fix your old website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have two stylesheets within an html page. In the stylesheet within the page will override the external one based on the cascading order. I thinks its: external styles - internal styles - inline styles

Here is a link with more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Yes, but as i said they are colliding... So the one css isn't allowed to apply at the other....

Comment: As I said In the stylesheet within the page will override the external one based on the cascading order

Answer (score 0):

Answer. Yes, you can apply more than one stylesheet to an HTML file. For each stylesheet you link to a page, you would just need to add an additional  element. When linking multiple CSS files, the styles are applied in the order that they are linked in the HTML document.